# Can I get the current url of an iframe if CORS between my website and the third party site is enabled? If so, how?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I'm working on a website that acts as a hub for multiple website and has a navigation bar on the side with links to each that will get rendered in an iframe when clicked. I'm trying to make it so you can leave one of those tabs and then when you go back, it will pick up from where you left off.

When I try to get the current url using iframe.contentWindow.location.href, I obviously get same-origin policy errors. I know you can use window.postMessage() to at least allow communication between the window and iframe but that still doesn't make iframe.contentWindow.location.href work. If I enable CORS with my website inside of the 3rd party sites with http headers, how should I get the current url of the iframe?

The servers of the 3rd party sites are linux servers and my website is made with React + Vite. Not looking for a full solution to my code, just pointers to help me get going in the right direction.

Comment: CORS is only relevant for cross-origin _network_ access (i.e. when you send a request from your frontend to some backend on a different origin). It's not relevant for cross-origin _object_ access (i.e. accessing an iframe on a different origin).

Comment: @jub0bs Oh okay. Is there any way you know of that allows me to get the current url in the iframe if I own the website it is rendering or am I out of luck with that? More specifically if the other website is written in a different language? I was thinking if I set up message listeners in both programs then they might be able to communicate and share that information.

Comment: @jub0bs Also just wanna make sure we're thinking the same thing. After reading your answer again do you think I'm trying to access an iframe on a different website than mine? If so then I mean that the iframe is on my website so the origin of the iframe itself is the same as my websites origin (at least that is my understanding). What I'm trying to access is the current url of the iframe contentWindow. not sure if this changes anything but i hope it does (i'm desperate lol)

Comment: If the framing document and framed document are on different Web origins, the former is not allowed to directly read the location (URL) of the latter. However, the postMessage API is one way to communicate between cross-origin documents. Have a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage